# Why does Pandora advance songs randomly?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-droid-incredible, music

I use Pandora **a lot**. Unfortunately, I've noticed that when using headphones at work it randomly skips songs very often. It might jump to the next track after just 30-90 seconds, etc.

It's very, very annoying. What is going on?

I'm usually on solid 3G when this happens but not exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

<s>[This solution](http://androidforums.com/incredible-support-troubleshooting/173334-pandora-skipping.html) seems to help--not too sure yet. My phone might think I'm intentionally skipping songs by way of headphone buttons I don't even have. The solution seems pretty simple and effective: install the Headset Blocker widget (free in the Market).</s>

Note: you might need to restart pandora *after enabling the block* for it to kick in (not sure).

I'll know in the next few hours if this helps or not...

OK, three skips in the last 10 minutes...this isn't helping at all! I'll leave it here as an failed option for future browsers.